# Add every x rows to my data

Tags: r

Let's say I'm not able to save everything in one run. I have a limitation where I can only save 20 rows each time.

Example:

```
nrow(iris)
intervals <- nrow(z)/20
new_iris <- iris[1:20, ]
new_iris <- rbind(new_iris, iris[21:41, ])
new_iris <- rbind(new_iris, iris[22:42, ])
new_iris <- rbind(new_iris, iris[43:53, ])
...
```

How can I do this `rbind` without specifying every 20 rows manually?

Comment: `split(iris, rep(1:nrow(iris), each=20, length.out=nrow(iris)))`? The final group may end up with fewer than 20... Not really clear if you're splitting or combining here since you create `intervals` and then ignore it.

Comment: [Why accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer helps other people with the same question. I would go with @J.Con answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
library(dplyr)
new_iris<-iris %>%
        group_by(grp =  as.integer(gl(n(), 20, n())))
```

Comment: Do you need to load any packages to get that to work?

Comment: Edited. Thanks @smacdonald

Comment: Does it need `magrittr`, too?

Comment: @smacdonald shouldn't do... I tried it loading `dplyr` alone.

Comment: the `%>%` operator from magrittr gets imported automatically when you load dplyr